# Warning message shown when setting UITableViewHeaderFooterView background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, contentview

```
class TableViewHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
```

When set color to UITableViewHeaderFooterView, I got following warning message and color is set to HeaderView. When try to resolved warring message  self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red the color is not about to set.

> Changing the background color of UITableViewHeaderFooterView is not
> supported. Use the background view configuration instead.

Do need to ignore warning message for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` setting background color?

Comment: I found that changing the background color property in IB to Default stops the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create UIView and then apply there the color

your code should be like this:

```
self.backgroundView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: `.red` is a UIColor (same thing as writing `UIColor.red`). Your answer most likely won't affect the warning.

Comment: Changing the background color of UITableViewHeaderFooterView is not supported. Use the background view configuration instead.  Still getting this message